# Child hairs not distributing correctly

Tags: hair

I have drawn a bunch of hairs on a mesh with the grooming tools, and was planning to use them as guide hairs, but when I add children hairs, it completely changes the distribution of the hairs across the mesh. It is putting much fewer hairs in the areas where the hair is shorter. Is there a way I can make the child hairs have the same density as the guide hairs? Here is an example: [image]

Comment: I think it may be related to your [child clump](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/children.html#interpolated) settings. Being short, if they are clumped together at the root you won't see them.